# Nuxt auth request with token works but custom request fails

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to connect my client from nuxt to laravel api. Where I used nuxt/auth module and connected it to login/logout/mydata endpoints.

Logout and mydata require Bearer token and by default nuxt/auth module. Those requests work without problems. But when I want to add additional requests for lets say posts I use:

```
async asyncData ({ app }) {
    let response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts', {}, 
    { headers: { 'Authorization': app.$auth.getToken('local'), 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } }
    )
    return {
      posts: response.data
    }
  },
```

I always get 401 error as unauthorized. Even tho this work from POSTMAN and from auth module requests....

Comment: May be you are missing `Bearer`, so try with `'Authorization': `Bearer ${app.$auth.getToken('local')}``  (you can use backticks)

Comment: I am not missing Bearer I output the value to check, also the fix was to pass just `headers: { 'Authorization': app.$auth.getToken('local') }` as second parameter.